# .htaccess deny access to login page via (partial) IP range?

Tags: .htaccess

This code works great:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
# To Allow
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.111$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-site.com/denied.html
</IfModule>
```

My question is, my IP Range changes often but the first 6 digits are always the same...I thought this would be work but it crashes the site:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.*\.*$
```

Is that not correct? Any ideas how to make it work so that the page is accessible by the first 6 digits of an IP Address?

Thanks!

Comment: the dot is escaped with "\", so `\.*` means "any number of backslashes, and not "a backslash with anything after". Have you tried `!^123\.456\..*\..*$`, or even better `!^123\.456\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Kaddath

This worked well:

```
!^123\.456\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$
```